# calling a function in controller from a view and using remap to route in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am not able to call a controller function from my view

This is my view code

```
echo "<a href='".$base_url."/qst/d/".$row['id']."' class='btn linkcolor'>DENY</a>";
```

which calls a controller qst and a function deny in it

here is my controller code

```
    public function _remap($method, $params = array()) {
        if ($method == 'd') {
            $this->deny();
        }
    }
    public function deny($id){
   }
```

am getting the error undefined varaible id.

also am getting Missing argument 1 for qst::d

can anyone tell me what's missing in the code so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use routes? In application/config/routes.php, add:

```
$route['qst/d/(:num)']= 'qst/deny/$1';
```

Comment: $1 will route to $id? And should i write the above code in _remap function?

Comment: Yup that's the idea, no _remap function needed.

Comment: @user3851607 add it to application/config/routes.php - no need for a _remap function.

Comment: nope its not working! the function deny is not getting called!

Comment: Have you removed the _remap function? The route setting above should definitely work, assuming qst is your controller, and deny is your method.

Comment: Also, in your view, is `$row['id']` set? Can you see an id in that link?

Comment: no i can't remove to _remap method because many other functions are also getting routed from the same. The problem is coming in passing of the variable id. Yes it is set.

Comment: `$this->deny();`does not hold $id as a param, so it's not passed on to the deny() function...

Comment: I edited it to $this->deny($id) . Now the error is Undefined variable: id

Comment: See the manual: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping I'll say it again though, the right way to do this is with routes...

Comment: hey it worked. instead of id I put $this->deny(params[0]); Thanx a lot for your help and the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your link only has /d/ for the method name, shouldn't this be /qst/deny/?

EDIT: Also, perhaps you should set a default for the ID and then check to see if the ID is default. (Perhaps null and an is_null check?) Have you var_dump'ed something within the deny method to verify that is the method running?

Comment: that's why am using _remap to route from d to deny!

Comment: Gotcha! Well, it looks like you're not passing anything to $this->deny(). How would it know the $id?

Comment: what's the syntax to pass something from _remap. I am passing id from the view.